# Can IATA code for an airport be more or less than 3 letters?

Tags: iata

I got an exercise where IATA codes are involved - exercise's specification says those codes can be 2-4 letters. After a few minutes of research I see that those codes should be 3 letters, so c**an IATA code for an airport be more or less than 3 letters**?

Comment: IATA codes for **what?** Different kinds of codes have different number of letters.

Comment: question edited

Comment: IATA codes for airports have 3 letters, while IATA codes for airlines have two.

Comment: [IATA codes for meals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_code) have 4 letters. I don't know of any airport though that does not have a 3 letter code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IATA themselves [say it's a three-letter code](http://www.iata.org/services/Pages/codes.aspx):

> Airlines and CRSs [computer reservations systems] may request the
>   assignment of a unique three-letter code to identify an airport

The [UN trade locations coding](http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/cefact/locode/unlocode_manual.pdf) also says the same thing:

> when a three-letter code is used alone to indicate a location, it
>   designates the name of an airport or location as adopted by IATA
>   (whose code only has three letters)

According to Wikipedia, IATA has several [different types of code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_code) that can be from one to four characters, but airport codes specifically are always three based on all the sources I mentioned.